# Xamarin Forms - C# - Async and Await Not Working?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, async-await

I'm struggling with *async and await* methods in C#.

I want to make sure my "clientToken" variable is populated before proceeding with the API call.

I then put an `await` method in front of the function `gateway.ClientToken.Generate();` but it's returning an error:

> Error CS1061: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here's my code:

```
public Braintree()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Task task = GetBraintreeToken();
        }

private async Task GetBraintreeToken()
        {
            var gateway = new BraintreeGateway
            {
                Environment = Environment.SANDBOX,
                MerchantId = "xxxx",
                PublicKey = "xxx",
                PrivateKey = "xxxx"
            };

            var clientToken = await gateway.ClientToken.Generate();

            Result<PaymentMethodNonce> result_nonce = gateway.PaymentMethodNonce.Create(clientToken);
         }
```

Comment: If the `Generate` method contains code that can run async, you could change the method to an `async Task<string>` instead of `string` and call async methods from there. If not, then there's no point in making this method async and you won't be able to await it. You can only await Tasks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disregarding any other problem, [`Generate`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/client-token/generate/dotnet) just returns a `string`.

> Returns a string which contains all authorization and configuration
> information your client needs to initialize the client SDK to
> communicate with Braintree.

To your question

> I want to make sure my "clientToken" variable is populated before
> proceeding with the API call.

All you need to do is remove the `await`, *strings* are not an *awaitable* and the function returns synchronously and immediately

Also note, there is nothing to `await` in your method `GetBraintreeToken` so it doesn't need the `async` keyword or return a `Task`.

If you would like to run it *asynchronously*, you can call it from `Task.Run()` in your constructor or page `OnAppearing` event

E.g Given

```
private void GetBraintreeToken()
{ ...
```

You could

```
public Braintree()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Task.Run(() => GetBraintreeToken());
}
```